# Connecting to Mysql db in Excel

Tags: mysql, excel, vba

So, I have to write a piece of code at my internship to link some excel worksheets with a MySQL DB and keep them updated, so far I have this but it keeps giving me errors. Do you see any mistakes? 
Thanks for reading.

The error I get is: runtime error -2147217900 automation error.

PS: I'm very new to VBA

```
Dim server_name As String
Dim database_name As String
Dim user As String
Dim Password As String
Dim rs As adodb.Recordset
Dim naam As String
Dim oConn As adodb.Connection


Public Sub getSerieNummer()

Dim result As String
Dim b As Long
Dim strSQL As String

naam = Range("C1").Value

server_name = "servername"
database_name = "dbname"
user_id = "idname"
Password = "password"

Set oConn = New adodb.Connection
oConn.Open "SERVER=" & server_name _
& ";PORT=3306" _
& ";DATABASE=" & database_name _
& ";UID=" & user_id _
& ";PWD=" & Password & _
";DSN=name_in_odbc;"

strSQL = "SELECT [serial_number] FROM view_aix WHERE [name] ='" & naam & "';"
Set rs = oConn.Execute(strSQL)

b = 0
With rs
    Do Until .EOF
    b = b + 1
    result = !serial_number
    rs.MoveNext
    Loop
End With
    oConn.Close
    rs.Close
Set rs.ActiveConnection = Nothing
Set oConn = Nothing
Range("C2").Value = result

End Sub
```

Comment: You need to provide details of the errors .. does it even connect? (`naam`  must be single-quoted if its a string)

Comment: Is it necessary to write code... If not then go through this tutorial http://helpdeskgeek.com/office-tips/excel-to-mysql/

Comment: Still getting the same error after inserting single quotes in my sql string. I guess I have to code it since the excel sheet was already created and I have to insert the data from the database in certain cells in the excel sheet. I don't think you can do that without coding.

Comment: At what line do you get the error? Also you should think about using parameters rather than embedding naam in the string like that or you run the risk of sql injections, but that is an issue for after you get this working.

Comment: I get the error at line: Set rs = oConn.Execute(strSQL)

Comment: Do a Debug.Print of your sql string and throw it in mysql and see if it works. You seem to be connecting to the database, it is failing to execute the query.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL do not support "[" instead use " ` ".

Maybe is your connection string the problem.

ODBC Connection Style

```
Driver={mySQL};Server=localhost;Option=16834;Database=myDataBase;
```

OLEDB Connection Style

```
Provider=MySQLProv;Data Source=mydb;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```